# Plant-based gunpowder?

Tags: warfare, flora, weapons

How about a plant which could produce a gunpowder-like substance, which can be used in explosives and firearms of at least medieval level, so that it can be harvested just like fruit, vegetables, cotton, tobacco or any other plant-based products?

How would it change wars (I imagine farmland becoming strategically important), how would said plant have evolved, look and be constructed, and what would the "gunpowder" be like?

Also, what would the safety regulations on gunpowder farms be? I imagine no open fire, no smoking, etc...

Comment: Everybody abandons the country during forest fire season.

Comment: This sounds like two questions to me: how would it happen, and what would be the effect. Both vastly different questions, requiring expertise in completely different fields.

Comment: Would they eventually get cultivated in a minefield?

Comment: Split this into two questions (one to design the plant, one to discuss its effects), and you'll have a good question here.

Answer (score 1):

First: What would such a plant look like?

Think pinecone. Pinecones are designed to open up after a forest fire and exploit all the nutrients and space that was just opened up by all that fire. So let's imagine a dry coniferous forest with pretty dense, spindly, resinous undergrowth so it burns hot and fast and completely. Weathering the fire isn't really an option.

A closed container filled with oxidizers(nitrates or maybe phosphates or even acetone peroxide) and simple fats or sugars (note: this is expensive in terms of nitrogen, but given the time between fires this may be worth it for the plant) hangs off the plant. Maybe it drops off when warmed. Come firetime, the heat from the blaze sets off the explosive and the seeds are fired every which way as shrapnel. Some will pass through the blaze and land safely in the already-burned area. Some will not. C'est la vie.

Natural selection should ensure fairly slow detonation speeds and fairly large seed shrapnels for more distance. Grow yourself an orchard and manually select the best trees for more explosive power and larger fruits.

In terms of warfare: Who knows. Grenades would be really easy to invent?

Comment: I think it's one of Larry Niven's "Known Universe" stories that has interplanetary trees, which reproduce by growning booster rockets that launch seeds into space.  Also, there are plant species (California poppies, for one) that have something like explosive seed dispersal, though it's by spring tension in the drying seed capsule.

Comment: Wood ash is fertile so there could be some evolutionary sense behind it all  - the phoenix tree. Maybe this happens if the soil isn't nourishing enough for some reason, or the tree becomes too old/sick/weak to be able to secure it's persistance and like falling leaves the trea looses the fruit capsules with the flammable substance which fall to the ground, dry and ignite/explode. Maybe it's a dust explosion of some natural flour-like powder inside the capsules

Comment: (but this is only guessing/inventing, I don't have any scientific foundation on that and I also don't know how effective such dust explosions would prove as gunpowder.)